# Upload a sketch via ISP?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno

Is it somehow possible to upload a sketch to an arduino by connecting another arduino? It tried it as you would do it when you want to burn the bootloader. The blink sketch worked on both arduinos, but it stopped when i disconnected the isp arduino.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you're doing it correctly, when you're uploading using one arduino as an ISP programmer, only the target should be running said sketch after the upload. You have to upload the Arduino as ISP sketch to the programmer and then send the blink sketch using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> or in Sketch -> Upload using the programmer.

More info: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP#toc2

But if what I said was just non-sense and you're sure you're uploading in the correct way, the problem is that when you take the ISCP connector the Arduino keeps resetting. Upload the code, disconnect everything, then just turn on the arduino with the blink sketch.